# SVG image is scaling instead of expanding

Tags: c#, uwp

```
<Canvas Background="AliceBlue">
    <TextBlock x:Name="MessageBox" Text="Press the black holder and drag to change Size" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="13"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Height_block"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Width_block"></TextBlock>
    <Border x:Name="Holder" Height="8" Width="8" Background="Black"/>
    <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Purple">
        <Image x:Name="image" Source="{StaticResource svg_source}" />
    </Border>
</Canvas>
```

I have added an SVG as a child to a border, and set its height and width to the border's height and width but the image is scaling and not expanding. I have set height and width property of the SVG to auto. What should I do?

How to expand SVG to the given height? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHnQ7.png)

Comment: Have you checked my reply?

Answer (score 0):

[UWP supports SVG image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.svgimagesource?view=winrt-22621),  the application layout will dictate the appropriate size for the SVG to decode at. It is recommended to check your `svg_source`, whether the [width and height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw3iU.png) have been set in svg. If it has already been set, it is recommended that you delete them.

Comment: Thanks for your response ,the height and width of the svg is set to auto